# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener') in laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, events, laravel-blade

I'm trying to validate a form in laravel blade with JS. It is giving me Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null. I have used same procedure with other pages and it is working fine.

here is the form

```
  <form action="#" method = "POST">
                                @csrf
                                <div class="form-row">
                                    <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
                                        <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="fname" name = "first_name" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" >
                                        <div id="namevalid" class="form-text text-muted invalid-feedback">
                                            Your name should be 3-15 characters long and shouldn't contain a number
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
                                        <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
                                        <input type="text"name = "last_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" required pattern="[a-zA-Z]([0-9a-zA-Z]){4,30}" min="4" max="30" title="Min 4 Max 30 Chars No Spaces No Special Charachters">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
                                        <label for="subject">Subject</label>
                                        <input type="text" name = "subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject" required pattern = '[a-zA-Z]([0-9a-zA-Z]){4,50}' min="5" max="50" title="Max Length exceeded of 50 chars and Single Word Subject e.g wedding">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <label for="email">Email</label>
                                        <input type="text" name ="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required pattern="([a-zA-Z0-9_\-.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]){2,7}" title="Only . allowed no Spaces no special characters">
                                <label for="message">Your Mesaage</label>
                                <textarea name ="message" class="form-control mb-3" placeholder="Type Here" id="" cols="10" rows="5" required min="5" max ="5000" title="Message cannot be empty"></textarea>
                                <button type = "submit"class="btn btn-success float-right">Send Message</button>
                            </form>
```

here is the JS code

```
 const fname= document.getElementById('fname');
    console.log(fname)

    fname.addEventListener('blur', ()=>{
        console.log("first name is blurred");
        // First name Validation
        let regex = /^[a-zA-Z]$/;
        let str = fname.value;
        console.log(regex, str);

        if(regex.test(str)){
            console.log('First name is valid');
            fname.classList.remove('is-invalid');
        }
        else{
            console.log('Last name is not valid');
            fname.classList.add('is-invalid');
        }
    })
```

Comment: Where do you get this error? In the console? If so, which line does it say is the error?

Comment: fname.addEventListener('blur', ()=>{ }

Comment: Try checking if `fname` is null before attaching event listener. `if(fname) { fname.addEventListener(.....); } else { console.log('fname is null'); }`. If the result is `fname is null` then it's obvious where the problem is.

Comment: Yes, I did check, It was null. I replaced my entire form. Since I was in a hurry. The bug is gone but I appreciate your help. Thanks, mate.